# ASP.Net asyncfileupload control in JQueryUI modal dialog

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, asyncfileupload

We are in the final stages of moving an older web application from the asp.net 2.0 environment to asp.net 4.0.  We've got everything ironed out but a file upload implementation.

We use an asyncfileupload control within a JQueryUI modal dialog...which runs well under 2.0 but not under 4.0, the control simply does not fire the UploadedComplete server-side event.

Our testing indicates the same code will run outside of the JQueryUI dialog, but not when in the dialog...so we assume the issue relates to JQueryUI under 4.0.

Seen one or two very old posts suggesting JQuery moves the upload control outside the form element, and thus the control doesn't fire, but that doesn't answer the question as to why our original implementation runs under 2.0 but not 4.0.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the right enctype="multipart/form-data" .

Hope these links already answered ,gives you some help

1. [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592789/asp-net-ajax-asyncfileupload-control-not-firing-server-side-onuploadcompleted-ev),
2. [ASPNet-Button-do-PostBack-in-jQuery-Modal-Dialog-Popup](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-make-ASPNet-Button-do-PostBack-in-jQuery-Modal-Dialog-Popup.aspx)